# Remove Theme from MapInfo TAB file

Tags: symbology, mapinfo, tab, thematic-map

I have been supplied with a MapInfo TAB file and when opened in MapInfo 15.2 (64bit) the layer is displayed along with a Thematic Theme Layer.

The symbology generated by the Thematic Theme no longer reflects the data within the browser. For example, a point which should be coloured red according to a particular column is displaying as blue.

How do I remove the Thematic Theme so it doesn't appear when opening the TAB file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the thematic map (Alt+F9), and check "Remove Default Theme View".

If you do not want to see any default themes, uncheck "Automatically Open Default Theme" in the "Map Window" preferences.